# Ionic + Nuxt.js v-model doesn't pass data

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, nuxt.js

I have created a basic app with Ionic + Nuxt.js, and using some of the ion-components. But the components don't seem to have their normal behavior. Using v-model, doesn't sync the data to the data function.

IE:

```
<ion-item>
  <input v-model="email" type="email" name="email"> <<< WORKS
  <ion-label position="floating">Email Address {{ email }}</ion-label>
  <ion-input v-model="email" type="email" name="email"></ion-input> <<< DOES NOT
</ion-item>


data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: null
    }
  },
```

Some more scope of this ion-item is wrapped in ion-app / ion-grid / row-cols. Also, running the latest versions of all (2021/05/18).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you use Ionic 5. When you use Ionic 5 and Vue 3 your solution should work.

BUT when you use Ionic 4 you need to use `@IonChange=""`

and check that you importet `IonInput` correct.

Comment: Hmm, i'm using Ionic 5.6.6, and Nuxt.js 2.15, so with Nuxt, you don't need to import the components, it's supposed to auto-import.

Comment: I tried both ways for the sake of testing, no luck still.